intuitive thinking for solving ratio-based matchstick problem
I came across the following problem and attempted to solve it using my intuition. My goal isn’t to find the correct answer, 32, but to understand whether my method is valid and to what extent. I’d appreciate any feedback.
I wanna learn more about my intuition. I'm assuming I'm in a cave and have no idea about algebra etc. and I wanna solve a problem I faced given I have only single chance, limited time, and no math skill.
Also my goal is to better understand the "search in search space" without any formalization or using any methods.
I also want to know much more about the way we as a human approximate, bayesian reasoning, uncertainty(for this problem, number of matches in each box) and how we try to fill it with our real world knowledge(for example, matchboxes maybe almost full etc.), and how my wrong approximated solution, 28, is close to actual solution, 32, knowing it maybe a coincidence.
The Problem:
In matchbox A, the ratio of unlit to lit matches is 7:2. In matchbox B, the ratio of unlit to lit matches is 5:3. The total number of matches in both boxes is 100. What is the total number of lit matches?
My intuitive solution (Grouping/Batching Approach):
Assumption:
I read the ratios as not strict. Under this I believe it's correct to think that one possible combination is 6x9=54 and 5x8=40 and 6 remaining(5 unlit and 1 lit) thus 100 total.
Grouping Matches:
For matchbox A, the ratio 7:2 means that in one "batch," there are 7 unlit + 2 lit = 9 matches.
For matchbox B, the ratio 5:3 means that in one "batch," there are 5 unlit + 3 lit = 8 matches.
Combining both boxes, one "batch" would have 9 + 8 = 17 matches.
Total Batches: Since the total number of matches is 100, I divided 100 by 17 to find the number of batches: 100 ÷ 17 ≈ 5.88.
Calculating lit Matches:
In each batch, there are 2 burned matches from A + 3 burned matches from B = 5 lit matches.
For 5 full batches, the total burned matches would be 5 × 5 = 25.
For the fractional batch (0.88 × 17 ≈ 15 matches), I assumed 12 unlit and 3 lit matches.
Adding these, the total burned matches would be 25 + 3 = 28.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzle Stack Exchange)!

Your assumption that the ratios don't need to be precise is certainly wrong.  This kind of problem usually gives precise conditions that lead to enough restrictions to bring the number of solutions down to one.
Here, the trick is to understand that the 100 matches must be expressed exaclty as a number of batches of 9 and a number of batches of 8 matches.
The simple way to search is to check for 1, 2, 3, ... batches in box A and see if the number of matches remaining for box B is a multiple of 8.
You can reduce the search space by noticing that box B must contain an even number of matches, and the the total, 100, is also even.  Therefore the number of matches in box A is even, which requires an even number of batches in box A.
Another simple way that works in this case is to notice that 8 and 9 are just one unit different.  If you make only batches of 8, you get 12 batches and 4 matches remaining.  Use these matches to convert 4 batches into batches of 9, resulting in 4 batches of 9 and 8 batches of 8.  This gives you one solution.  It doesn't guarantee there are not others.

So we have two kinds of batches, consisting of $9$ and $8$ matches, respectively. Your solution is based on an additional assumption that the number of instances of batches of each kind is the same. But this assumption is wrong because $17$ does not divide $100$. Instead we have to look for ways to split $100$ matches into batches of these kinds. A brute force check shows that this is possible only when there are
$4$ batches of $9$ matches and $8$ batches of $8$ matches. Therefore the number of lit matches is $4\cdot 2+8\cdot 3=32$ matches.

+1 nice, because you do not use variables and appeal more directly to intuition than to algebra

I added the basis of my assumption to my question.

The 'batches' argument should be about pairs

 each batch from first box having 2 lit matches


 each batch from second box having 3 lit matches

Then it is a matter of finding amounts

 amount x of batches from first and amount y of batches from second box


 with $9x + 8y = 100$ (reaching this step needs some first order equation calculation using $7+2=9$ and $5+3=8$)


 giving (trial and error within reasonable constraints) $x = 4$ and $y = 8$

and total lit matches

 $2*x + 3*y = 8 + 24 = 32$

